# How to fix Vector2.Distance() method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a game where I use objects that have their own gravity. Im using the Vector2.Distance method. When the objects start going closer to eachother, the distance gets smaller, but when it gets to 2 it starts to get bigger again.

```
foreach (Rigidbody2D body in allRigidBodies)
{
    if (body.gameObject.layer == 8 && body.name != ThisBodyName)
    {
         AvrgPosition2D += body.position;
         AvrgMass += body.mass;
         count++;
    }
}
AvrgPosition2D = AvrgPosition2D / count;

AvrgPosition3D = AvrgPosition2D;

distance = Vector2.Distance(AvrgPosition3D, ThisBodyRB.position);

force = GravConstant * AvrgMass * ThisBodyMass / (distance * distance);

ThisBodyRB.AddForce(AvrgPosition3D * (float)force * Time.deltaTime);

AvrgMass = 0;
AvrgPosition2D -= AvrgPosition2D;
count = 0;
```

I also tried (AvrgPosition - ThisBodyRB.position).magnitude, but that didnt change anything.

Also, I have this script on 2 objects, but they dont output the same distance.

Comment: At a guess I'd say it's because they meet and then move apart, and the reason it goes down to 2 is due to the size of the objects and thats the distance from the center of each object when they meet.

Comment: @akaBase I fixed the original problém I was having, it was because I forgot I already filtered the object running the script from the AveragePosition, so I subtracted it later.

Comment: @akaBase But now I have a problem that the object gets sometimes repeled instead of being pulled to eachother

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line:

```
AvrgPosition2D = AvrgPosition2D - ThisBodyRB.position;
```

Is likely the problem. The positions you are comparing are the location of the body in question and the average location of all bodies - the location of the body in question.

As far as I can tell this line is not necessary at all since you are not considering the location of the current body anyway when getting the average location.

Comment: Im so dump, Thank you